# Scikit-learn: Loading images from folder to create a labelled dataset for KNN classification

Tags: python, file, scikit-learn, directory

I want to do handwritten digit recognition using K-Nearest Neighbours classification with scikit-learn. I have a folder that has 5001 images of handwritten digits (500 images for each digit from 0-9).

[image]

I am trying to find a way to create a dataset based on these images, so that I can then create a training and testing set. I have read a lot of online tutorials about how to do K-Nearest Neighbours classification using scikit-learn but most of the tutorials load existing datasets such as the MNIST dataset of handwritten digits.

Is there any way to create your own dataset by reading images from a folder and then assigning a label to each image? I am not sure what methods I can use to do this. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the data you should do something like this :

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mypath = '.' # edit with the path to your data
files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

x = []
y = []

for file in files:
    label = file.split('_')[0] # assuming your img is named like this "eight_1.png" you want to get the label "eight"
    y.append(label)
    img = plt.imread(file)
    x.append(img)
```

Then you will need to manipulate a little bit x and y before give it to scikit learn but you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Pillow or opencv libraries to read your images.

#### For Pillow:

```
from PIL import Image 
import numpy as np

img = PIL.Image.open("image_location/image_name") # This returns an image object   
img = np.asarray(img) # convert it to ndarray
```

#### For Opencv:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image_location/image_name", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

To convert all of your images you can use, for example, os library:

```
import os
```

Create a list of your images names

```
loc = os.listdir('your_images_folder')
```

To store **grayscale** images with one color channel you can use an empty array

```
data = np.ones((# of images, image_size wxh))


  for i, l in enumerate(loc):

     # Full image path
     path = os.path.join("your_images_folder", l)

     img = np.asarray(PIL.Image.open(path))

     # Make a vector from an image
     img = img.reshape(-1, img.size)

     # store this vector
     data[i,:]  = img
```

As a result, wou will get numpy array "data" for your classification project.
"y" vector can be added also in the same loop from the name of each image.

To trace your process with a progress bar in a loop sometimes tqdm library can be a proper solution.
To store rgb images you can implement the same solution. For rgb images `img.reshape(-1, )` will return your a longer vector.

Comment: What does the -1 do in img.reshape(-1, img.size)?

Comment: I made a mistake, `img.reshape(-1, )` makes 1d vector from an image array, `img.reshape(-1,  img.size)` and `img.reshape(1,  img.size)` behave the same.

-1 means that numpy will find the proper shape automatically.  `reshape(-1, )`- get the proper shape for 1d vector.

Comment: After making your X dataset you can save it as a pandas DataFrame or save it simply by np.save('data.npy').

Answer (score -1):

Does this help?

```
import os
import imageio


def convert_word_to_label(word):

    if word == 'zero':
        return 0
    elif word == 'one':
        return 1
    elif word == 'two':
        return 2
    elif word == 'three':
        return 3
    elif word == 'four':
        return 4
    elif word == 'five':
        return 5
    elif word == 'six':
        return 6
    elif word == 'seven':
        return 7
    elif word == 'eight':
        return 8
    elif word == 'nine':
        return 9



def create_dataset(path):
    X = []
    y = []

    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for image in f:
            if '.jpg' in image:
                image_path = os.path.join(r, image)
                img = imageio.imread(image_path)
                X.append(img)
                word = image.split('_')[0]
                y.append(convert_word_to_label(word))
    return X, y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    X, y = create_dataset('path/to/image_folder/')
```